Looking for a video editor to easily do side-by-side comparisons of video clips
I'm trying to create a video where I compare two video clips side-by-side. In other words, I have one clip on the left (scaled to half size) and the other on the right (scaled to half size), and some text on the bottom of the video. Optimally, it should be easy to start playing one video from an arbitrary point, perhaps jump to a different part of that video (possibly with a fade-out + fade-in), pause it (so that its current still image remains visible) and start the other video at a particular point, pause that, start playing the first video from a particular point, and so on.
I'm looking for a free video editor for Windows (or for Linux) that allows easily doing that. I have tried VSDC and OpenShot, and unless I'm missing something neither allows doing that very easily, and it's really laborious, time-consuming and awkward to achieve that. I also tried looking at DaVinci Resolve, but it requires registering so I didn't bother going through that trouble without knowing in advance if it would allow easily doing that.

Most editors can do this Capcut & Resolve are good free options.
